# Is it acceptable to announce Area51 proposal

Tags: discussion

I created an Area 51 proposal, and would like to gather followers. I think my proposal will be of interest to users of technology oriented sites, such as Stack Overflow. Apart from [updating my profile description to include a link to the proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1461424/krumia), I thought of putting an announcement as a question, but I am not sure if it will be seen as spam.

Is it acceptable to post an announcement of an Area 51 proposal, if proposal creator thinks users of Stack Overflow will be interested in it? Or is it acceptable to post an announcement, and let the community evaluate the relevance by voting?

Comment: No, spam will not be accepted even if it's spam for another SE site or proposal. Questions should be questions, not announcements or promotions - this is true for meta as well as the normal SE sites. Feel free to post the link in relevant SE chatrooms though.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. I assure you that downvoting does not affect me emotionally or reputation-wise. But if you answer to the question is **no**, I don't think downvote is the way to express it. You can use an answer post or a comment.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because your question is answerable by using common sense and reading the basics about meta: Regardless of the fact that your post would be spammy, this is a site about Stack Overflow and your question has nothing to do with Stack Overflow. At least I figure that's the reasoning, I didn't actually vote on this at all.

Comment: @Krumia: of course it is; the OP is asking if there is a way to promote a Area51 proposal to SO members. This is a perfectly valid question to ask here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry I don't get you. You seem to be telling that question is off-topic ("of course it is"), and not off topic ("This is a perfectly valid question to ask here.") at the same time. BTW _I am_ the OP.

Comment: @Krumia - this question is perfectly acceptable here. What's not acceptable is what you are proposing **in the question**.

Comment: @Krumia sorry, I meant that *this post* does not need closing. I did not realise that the (now deleted) close message was yours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is still considered spam. Let's look at the definition:

> **spam** *(n)*
>
> 1. Irrelevant or inappropriate messages sent on the Internet to a large number of recipients.
> 2. Unwanted or intrusive advertising on the Internet.
> 3. Something about <strike>animal byproducts</strike> meat.

Your promotion of an Area 51 site would count as both numbers 1 and 2 in that definition, making it clearly spam.

If you remain unconvinced, here's another good reason: **that would not be a question**, so you cannot post it as such.

Comment: What if I rephrased the announcement to make it a question? :D **Would my Area51 proposal [Scientific Imagination](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=IPIEcsN2huMFuP7v0aO_3g2) duplicate existing StackExchange science sites?**, and accompany it with an answer to explain that [it is not a duplicate](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/17667/115322)?

Comment: @Krumia it would still be off topic for meta.SO because this site is about Stack Overflow, and your site proposal has nothing to do with Stack Overflow. It _might_ be on-topic for meta.SE, but I think asking it when you already know the answer would not be well received, because again, it's not a legit question.

Comment: @l4mpi: Yes I very well knew that the question would not be well received. Yet I asked it for the record. But did not think it was off topic because SO is a technology site. And yes, my rephrased question will fit Meta.SE, if it ever fits any meta.

Comment: @Krumia what does being a technology site have to do with it? Just because it's based on something Randall Munroe did doesn't make it programming related.

Comment: @l4mpi: Now what does Randal Munroe has to do with my comment? SO is technology related, and therefore I thought people will be interested in a proposal that is technology related. And you have explained me that the question is off topic and I have no arguments against that, I am perfectly fine with question getting closed. I asked because I did not think it off topic, and I could not find a similar question on meta.

Comment: @Krumia If you wanted to ask that question (in your first comment), you'd ask it [here on Area 51 Discuss](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com), not on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, or Meta Stack Exchange. Stack Overflow is not "a technology site". It is a Q&A site for [*computer programming*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Not everything about technology goes. And even advertising websites for computer programming is not acceptable—we expect all content on SO to be self-contained. A pointer to an external site violates this guideline, even if you disagree that it is spam.