# Is it acceptable to mention Area51 proposal in a comment or is it still a spam?

Tags: discussion, comments, spam

Following [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269820/1469208). Let's say, that I have an Area 51 site proposal (I don't have, I'm just speculating), which is 100% oriented / based on part of SO. That is -- it covers area now handled on SE with questions tagged with one or more specific tags. For example -- once there were questions about Drupal, which (as I think) at some point were extracted / migrated to newly created Drupal Answers.

Is it acceptable to place a comment about this proposal below some of questions tagged with this specific tag, to let people know, that such questions should now be asked at that proposed Area51 site?

Comment: Proposal != beta site/graduated site. You can't get answer on a proposal. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: You're right. But, hm... I could suggest, that the same question could be asked on Area51 as a example question.

Comment: `the same question could be asked on Area51 as a example question.` It will confuse the hell out of newbie - such thing should be removed one way or another (flag?). If there is already a site dedicated for a topic, I think it is fine to leave the comment there. But if say - a user keeps spamming comment telling people to go to a certain site, a flag is in order.

Comment: When a question was off topic on a certain SE site, but would be on-topic on a proposal, i left a link to the proposal and flagged for closure. But that's different than when it actually is on-topic.

Comment: @Scimonster It depends on whether new site will be created and SE politics. Did questions about Drupal become off-topic since creation of Drupal Answers?